# Webapi 2 enable impersonation on certain controllers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, impersonation

I have a webapi 2 application.  I have enabled impersonating a specific user using the below web.config.  Is it possible to impersonate this user only on certain controllers instead of the entire application.  I know that there's a way to use pinvoke to impersonate a specific domain user in code, but I would rather not use it.

```
<system.web>
    <identity impersonate="true" userName="mydomain\myuser" password="mypassword"/>
</system.web>
```

I have tried to put my controller inside an area, but the web config inside the area just doesn't apply to the web api 2 controller

Answer (score 0):

If you use Areas, you can accomplish this.

Create an Area and put your identity impersonate line in area's web.config.

See following for web.config [inheritance](http://weblogs.asp.net/jongalloway/10-things-asp-net-developers-should-know-about-web-config-inheritance-and-overrides).

Comment: I have put my web api 2 controller inside an area, but the web.config doesn't apply to the web api 2 controller.  web config just simply doesn't apply to Area and web api 2 controller.